# Oracle table change monitor

Tags: java, oracle

I have a java application that is connected to a view on a remote Oracle db.

Does anyone know of a way in Java to monitor this table for changes? I.e. if there are inserts of updates etc I would need to react.

Comment: Monitoring a database table for changes is a 'design smell'. You should consider introducing an Event Driven Architecture (EDA) supported by an Enterprise Service Bus (ESB). For example Mule (www.mulesoft.com).

Comment: Yep more buzzwords and "architecture" is always the right answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can place a INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE trigger on the table to perform some action when 'data' changes are made to the table.  (as opposed to changes to the structure of the table)

I believe 10g also supports triggers on views.

but I'm not sure how you can notifiy the java process of this other then by polling.

sorry.

you could possibly create some solution where the java app has a 'listen' server and the database pushes it back a message. but that sounds hard to maintain.

[Justin Cave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10397/justin-cave) in the comments suggests you could configure Oracle Streams to send out logical change records (LCRs) that a Java app could subscribe to via JMS. Or the trigger could write records to an Advanced Queue that Java could subscribe to via JMS.

you will still need to be wary of Oracle transations..
due to the way Oracle transactions work, the trigger will fire on the change, but it may also fire multiple times..

and in anycase the java app would not bee able to 'see' the changes until a commit had been performed.

Comment: Depending on how heavy the architecture needs to be, you can configure Oracle Streams to send out logical change records (LCRs) that a Java app could subscribe to via JMS.  Or the trigger could write records to an Advanced Queue that Java could subscribe to via JMS.

Comment: The problem is that Streams works at the object level, not sure you can configure Streams to send out LCRs for a view.  Is the view such that you can identify a handful of table(s) to subscribe to changes on and then poll the view to see if the row you're interested in really changed?

Comment: While it is true that triggers could get fired multiple times with a rollback in between, Oracle AQ/ Streams is transactional, so the enqueue action would be rolled back as well.  The only issue would be if you did something that cannot be rolled back in the trigger (i.e. send email).

Comment: FYI, I just learned when looking into Oracle Streams, they have deprecated that technology in Oracle 12c to replace it with another called GoldenGate which seems to attempt to address a number of needs related to replication and data streaming to external sources.

Answer (score 10):

Look at [Oracle Change Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_chngnt.htm#BABEECBE), a so interesting Oracle feature.

From the Oracle documentation: *"Database Change Notification is a feature that enables client applications to register queries with the database and receive notifications in response to DML or DDL changes on the objects associated with the queries. The notifications are published by the database when the DML or DDL transaction commits."*

Comment: Seems like it only works for PL/SQL or C callbacks but thats pretty much the stuff I need thanks - now how to wire it up to the java app ... :)

Comment: I believe that Oracle can call Java stored procedures, I just don't know how to do it.  http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/tech/java/jsp/oracle9ijsp.html might help, though.