# Notification of Oracle table changes in Java

Tags: java, oracle

I need to run a method in Java every time a specific table of an Oracle DB is updated (any sorts of updates, including record additions, deletions and modifications).

**What is the most efficient way do "poll" a table for changes from Java that has good performance and does not put too much pressure on the DB?**

Unfortunately I have many constraints:

- I can't create additional tables, triggers, stored procedures etc., because I have no control over the DB administration / design.
- I'd rather avoid [Oracle Change Notification](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dcn.htm), as proposed in that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337335/oracle-table-change-monitor), as it seems to involve C/JNI.
- Just counting the records is not good enough as I might miss modifications and simultaneous additions/deletions.
- a delay of up to 30/60s between the actual change and the notification is acceptable.
- The tables I want to monitor generally have 100k+ records (some 1m+) so I don't think pulling the whole tables is an option (from a DB load / performance perspective).

Comment: Starting from oracle 11g you can use Oracle Change Notification with plain JDBC driver http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm

Comment: Interesting thanks. I use the 11g client but the DB in itself is an older version (say 9.xx). Do you know which version matters?

Comment: Unfortunally I don't know if this will work with older Oracle versions

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov OK - I suppose I'll try and see if it works. Consider posting your comment as answer as it seems spot on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from oracle 11g you can use Oracle Change Notification with plain JDBC driver [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm)

Comment: With an 11.2 client and a 9.2 database, I get an exception - it looks like the database has to be 10.2+ for this to work :-(