# Refresh Jtable when change in database. Error :ORA-12519

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, database-connection, ora-12519

I'm a beginner in Java projects and I want to know the best way to do something.
I have developed a desktop application which show data from a table in database in a JTable, and when that table has a change, it has to show previous data + new records.

Well, I made a thread: 
First of all, Start, show all the data in a JTable, executing a query.
Thread: keep attention to database, executing a query, different from the first one, every X seconds.

It's supposed that every single connection after executing query is closed, but from time to time appears this error:

> Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12519,
>   TNS:no appropriate service handler found

I've read something about it exceeded the maximum number of proccesses admitted, and also probably I could solve it with Poolable Connection, but I'm not sure about how to do it. 
Could anyone help me with that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sure Oracle db has notifier ...

Comment: Are you managing the database as well ? because is a problem related to the database access! Can you post your connection string for us to see ?

Comment: At least initially, I can't manage the database. I use oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about oracle, but I tried a similar approach using the MS Access Database. Instead of a thread, I used the Timer and the TimerTask class to schedule my process to repeat after a fixed rate. There is a scheduleAtFixedRate method in the Timer class which helps you to schedule tasks in the thread pool. I think that should help. Look at the api for these classes for more information. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: The error is an listener error , has nothing to do with you app.

Answer (score 0):

In my research, I found these links quite interesting:

https://jirawong.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/oracle-database-change-notification-jdbc-style-example/

[Notification of Oracle table changes in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797940/notification-of-oracle-table-changes-in-java)

http://theblasfrompas.blogspot.com.es/2010/02/using-database-change-notification-dcn.html

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm

I'll try it hard to do it like that. Thanks!