# jdbc monitor oracle table change

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I have a java application and related oracle run in different server. I need to monitor a change on a table, if anything happens, log info in application server. I tried to use DatabaseChangeRegistration but the listener class dependency is at least 11g. Is ther any other way I can monitor the change on jdbc side since oracle version is 10g?

Tried Notification feature

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question? [Oracle table change monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337335/oracle-table-change-monitor)

As suggested by others in the thread, you can either use triggers or `DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION`.